# Вопрос с promises в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, promise

```
var cordinats = function () {
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    if(navigator.geolocation) { 
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var long = position.coords.longitude,
            lat = position.coords.latitude;
            var myLocation = {
                long: long,
                lat: lat
            };
            console.log('Оп1');
            resolve(myLocation);
            console.log(myLocation);
        }) 
    }
        var errObj = {
        0: "Unkonown Error",
        1: "Permission denied by User",
        2: "Position is not available",
        3: "Request Timed Out"
    }
    console.log('Оп2');
    reject(`${err.code} ${errObj[err.code] }`);
});
}

cordinats().then(function(location) {
    var loc = location;
    console.log(loc);
    changeHtmlInfo();
}, function(error) {

});
```

Я открываю код через Chrome. Сначала в консоли появляется Оп2. Потом при подтверждении данных о считывании геолокации - Оп1. Последный console.log(loc) вообще не выполняется. Вопрос:

1. почему такая последовательность выполнения кода
2. Почему не выполняется `cordinats().then`

Comment: Шесть скроллов кода - это сильно

Comment: Как обычно пишут модераторы, "В вопросе не видно работы мысли и желания разобраться в проблеме"
 Кроме того вы даже не написали что делает ваш код зачем он нужен на каком этапе возникает ошибка, а извини 6 скроллов читать из чистого альтруизма никто не будет

Comment: Ваш [mcve] недостаточно минимален и невоспроизводим

Comment: почему ты думаешь что `then` Не вызывается?

Comment: Потому что  console.log(loc); не выполняется. В консоли нет никакого результата. Даже undifined

Comment: @Evander он и не будет выполняться, так как `function(error) { console.log("UPS... Reject") }` выполнится гораздо раньше. Похоже `getCurrentPosition` асинхронный и в то время, как он до него дойдет, отмена произойдет раньше.

Comment: _Потому что console.log(loc); не выполняется._ - в методе `then` два параметра: первый отвечает за успешное разрешение обещания (resolve), второй за неуспешное (reject). Так как у тебя выводится `Оп2` - следом ты вызываешь `reject(...);` и плавно переходишь в функцию которую передал вторым параметром в `then`. Так как она пустая - ты ничего и не видишь

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. пойду разбираться.

Comment: Ну и вдобавок логика неверная: ты всегда делаешь сначала `reject`, даже если вошел в `if`, но так как внутри `if` операция асинхронная - ее колбэк будет выполняться _после_ завершения основной функции

Comment: поэтому нужно либо делать `return` внутри `if`, либо добавить ветку `else`

Comment: Всем спасибо за помощь. Заработало! Главное- я понял почему. )

Comment: Тогда либо добавь ответ с пояснением _почему_ и как решил, либо удали вопрос, так как он больше не воспроизводится :)

Answer (score 1):

### Почему не работало?

Метод `getCurrentPosition` - асинхронный. Это значит, что при заходе в `if` выполнение не останавливается, пока не выполнится callback, а проходит дальше, выходит из `if` и вызывает `reject`.

Метод [`then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) принимает два параметра: первый для успешного разрешения и второй - для не успешного.

Так как всегда вызывается `reject`, то всегда вызывалась функция переданная вторым параметром, и, так как она пустая, ничего не выводилось.

### Как исправить?

Например, можно избавиться от `if` и воспользоваться тем, что метод [`getCurrentPosition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition) тоже может принимать обработчик для ошибки. Теперь функция вызывается всегда и завершение Promise зависит от вызова соответствующего обработчика, достаточно просто вызвать в нужных местах `resolve` и `reject`.

```
function cordinats() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                var long = position.coords.longitude,
                lat = position.coords.latitude;
                var myLocation = {
                    long: long,
                    lat: lat
                };
                resolve(myLocation);
            }, function(err) {
                var errObj = {
                    0: "Unkonown Error",
                    1: "Permission denied by User",
                    2: "Position is not available",
                    3: "Request Timed Out"
                }
                reject(`${err.code} ${errObj[err.code] }`);
            });
    });
}

cordinats().then(function(location) {
    var loc = location;
    console.log(loc);
    changeHtmlInfo(loc);
}, function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: распиши подробнее, тем более ты не туда return добавил :-)

Comment: @Grundy ОК Я убрал в этой строчке `return resolve(myLocation);` return. Всё работает. Но теперь я не понимаю как вообще выполняется код. Promises используются для асинхронного выполнения кода, это я понимаю. Я не понимаю в какой последовательности этот код выполняется. Читать то я читал про promises, но пока что мои знания js не настолько глубоки чтобы понять пример в той статье [https://learn.javascript.ru/promise]. Есть те кто здесь, на примере моего кода, объяснит **в какой последовательности код выполняется**?

Comment: Отредактировал твой ответ.